# compare two arrays on key and create multiple array set value if key not match

Tags: php, arrays

I've two multiple Arrays with key=>value Data in them. For exapmle like this:

```
$k_a = array( array(
        "article" =>  "c",
        "price"   =>  2
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "f",
        "price"   =>  3
    )
); 

$k_b = array( array(
        "article" =>  "a",
        "price"   =>  2
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "b",
        "price"   =>  4
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "c",
        "price"   =>  1
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "g",
        "price"   =>  3
    )
);
```

An I've an array with all articles in it, but the price is set to zero.

```
$a_f = array( array(
        "article"=> "a", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "b", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "c", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "d", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "e", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "f", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "g", 
        "price"  => 0,
    ), array(
        "article"=> "h", 
        "price"  => 0,
    )
);
```

Now I want to check, if the values of the keys article in $k_a and $k_b exists in $a_f and create a new array with the values of the key price for that article. The other article should have the price zero. 
At the and I want to compare the two new arrays and remove the keys articles where the price is zero.

At the and the arrays should be like that:

```
$k_a_new =array( array(
        "article" => "a",
        "price"   => 0
    ), array(
        "article" => "b",
        "price"   => 0
    ), array(
        "article" => "c",
        "price"   => 2
    ), array(
        "article" => "f",
        "price"   => 3
    ), array(
        "article" => "g",
        "price"   => 0
    )          
);

$k_b_new = array( array(
        "article" => "a",
        "price"   => 2
    ), array(
        "article" => "b",
        "price"   => 4
    ), array(
        "article" => "c",
        "price"   => 1
    ), array(
        "article" => "f",
        "price"   => 0
    ), array(
        "article" => "g",
        "price"   => 3
    )            
);
```

The result array should contain all articles of both arrays, but the pirce of it own article if it exists. 
Are there functions or a specific way to solve this?

I've tried to loop over the arrays and show the same articles values, but don't know how change the price values or add the articles vlaues with the zero price?

```
echo "<br>";
foreach($k_b as $key_1=>$value_1){
    foreach($value_1 as $k_11=>$v_11){
        if($k_11 == "article"){
            foreach($a_f as $key_2=>$value_2){
                foreach($value_2 as $k_21=>$v_21){
                    if($k_21 === "article"){
                        if($v_11 === $v_21){
                            print_r($v_21);
                            echo "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "not very effective" doesn't tell us anything concrete about your problem. Please show your current code and explain what it outputs at the moment. We can't fix what we can't see. Thanks

Comment: you can get your result by two input array only,no need of third-one

Comment: @ADyson My Code doesn't make anything.. just loop over the arrays, so it's not necessary to show...

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you show me an example how?

Comment: so you're saying you haven't actually tried anything yet? There are lots of PHP functions which deal with arrays, matching keys, checking for existence of keys and values etc. Research is easy online. You should at least have made some attempt really before asking others to solve a complicated-sounding problem for you in their free time.

Comment: @Alex you have to show some code effort what you have tried so far

Comment: @ADyson this is my loop Code, but I don't know how to continue or to change and add vaules

Comment: This indicates you haven't really done any research then, because changing and adding values to arrays is not hard to find out about. If you're asking about the logic by which you do so, then that indicates you need to sit down, think through the process on paper and come up with an algorithm (i.e. a logical process for doing the task which could be automated by a computer). Then try to implement the algorithm. If you get stuck with attempting the _implementation_, come back with your attempt and we can help you further with the PHP-specific aspects (if google hasn't already helped you).

Comment: @Alex: I tried to understand the logic behind your question, and as explained it does not make sense to me.  Ex. you start with k_a, k_b and a_f.  Then you want two new arrays.  **no1** you say *if the values of the keys article in $k_a and $k_b exists in $a_f and create a new array with the values of the key price for that article*.  For me it means a:0,b:0,c:2 or 1,f:0,g:0.  From you sample output, you take the highest value for c.  Yet you arrive at a:0:,b:0,c:2,f:3,g:0.  why f:3?  It is not in k_b.  Explain your logic first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this:-

```
<?php

$k_a = array( array(
        "article" =>  "c",
        "price"   =>  2
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "f",
        "price"   =>  3
    )
); 

$k_b = array( array(
        "article" =>  "a",
        "price"   =>  2
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "b",
        "price"   =>  4
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "c",
        "price"   =>  1
    ), array(
        "article" =>  "g",
        "price"   =>  3
    )
);

$final_article_array = array_values(array_unique(array_merge(array_column($k_a,'article'),array_column($k_b,'article'))));
sort($final_article_array);

$k_a_new = [];
$k_b_new = [];
foreach($final_article_array as $key=>$final_article_arr){
    $k = array_search($final_article_arr,array_column($k_a,'article'));
    if($k !==false){
        $k_a_new[$final_article_arr]['article'] = $final_article_arr;
        $k_a_new[$final_article_arr]['price'] = $k_a[$k]['price'];
    }else{
        $k_a_new[$final_article_arr]['article'] = $final_article_arr;
        $k_a_new[$final_article_arr]['price'] = 0;
    }
    $j = array_search($final_article_arr,array_column($k_b,'article'));
    if($j !==false){
        $k_b_new[$final_article_arr]['article'] = $final_article_arr;
        $k_b_new[$final_article_arr]['price'] = $k_b[$j]['price'];
    }else{
        $k_b_new[$final_article_arr]['article'] = $final_article_arr;
        $k_b_new[$final_article_arr]['price'] = 0;
    }
}
$k_a_new = array_values($k_a_new);
$k_b_new = array_values($k_b_new);

print_r($k_a_new);
print_r($k_b_new);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/DTiJk

***Note:- explanation***

1)try to get all article values from `$k_a` and `$k_b`,merge them to get all article into one array,remove duplicates from this array and then re-index this array. Now sort this article array by value.

2) Iterate and check that the article present in $k_a and $k_b array or not (using `array_search`)

3)Now you get the index of child array  through `array_search()` if article found.

4)Based on this key get the price value of child array and add it to your final array with corresponding article.

5)If index is not there then put price 0 for that corresponding article in your final array.

***[Get all Php functions here](http://php.net/)***

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  He will never learn if we spoon feed him.

Comment: @Alive to Die thank you, I didn't know that there are functions like array_column() or array_search() for key value arrays